# Importing css library to ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, webpack

I am developing an ionic app and i am trying to use the flag-icon-css library (https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css). I have installed the library using npm install and added the library to my package.json file

I added the following to my app.scss file:

```
$flag-icon-css-path: '~flag-icon-css/flags' !default;
@import "~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon";
```

This path is not recognized and i get the following compilation error:

```
  sass: src/app/app.scss, line: 25 
  File to import not found or unreadable: ~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon. Parent style sheet: 
  /src/app/app.scss 

  L25:  @import "~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon";
```

When changing the path to relative notation, i.e:

```
$flag-icon-css-path: '../../node_modules/flag-icon-css/flags' !default;
@import '../../node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon';
```

The code compiles and the css classes are resolved but the app cannot resolve the path to the flags svg files, resulting in a 404 error.

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

module.exports = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: process.env.IONIC_OUTPUT_JS_FILE_NAME,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, provide your webpack configuration

Comment: @GONG, added the config

Comment: so, where is `scss` loader session?

Comment: @GONG, the scss files are loaded the problem is that the library tries to load the svg file from inside the node_modules which results in a 404

Comment: It is correct, you'd need a `file-loader` to properly handle files

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: It didn't work for me even if I am having file-loader.